# bash script to add prefix to line.

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have this list of data that I massaged into this. 
Some of the numbers are missing - as seen here in the 7th line that begins with CPB

```
232876337    ROK  37,314  37,314  RWCPRTN    116.4767  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:58:51  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232875608    CNC  2,000  2,000  WTCO    69.1813  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Limit   69.15  29Jul15 14:53:50  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232874715    ENS  23,987  23,987  NWQI    62.0525  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:47:32  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232872532    CPB  3,000  3,000  STNJ    48.6158  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:35:16  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232871384    XEC  2,500  2,500  ZKB    105.4786  UBS Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:32:39  XNYS  USD  Stock
CPB  3,000  3,000  STNJ    48.6424  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:16:59  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232863189    CPB  2,000  2,000  STNJ    48.6533  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 13:43:10  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232861168    CPB  4,000  4,000  STNJ    48.6842  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 13:26:01  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232856253    Y  7,853  7,853  SIM    18.2700  Fix Cad Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 12:46:50  XTSE  CAD  Stock  A4
232856254    MEG  48,300  48,300  SIM    14.8200  Fix Cad Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 12:46:50  XTSE  CAD  Stock  A4
232856255    FM  107,200  107,200  SIM    11.3000  Fix Cad Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 12:46:50  XTSE  CAD  Stock  A4
232856256    TD  34,200  34,200  SIM    52.6400  Fix Cad Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 12:46:50  XTSE  CAD  Stock  A4
```

I added a prefix with this hack script. It does not really matter what the number is - I am after the rest of the line - not exactly the unique identifier. 
Is their a more elegant way of doing this  - without echoing the $line into a sed replace.

```
while read line ; do 
 if  [[ $line =~ ^[0-9] ]] ; then 
   echo $line ; 
 else 
   echo $line | sed -e 's/^/0000000000 /';
fi ; 
done < /tmp/comeandplaywithus > /tmp/danny
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat /tmp/s
232876337    ROK  37,314  37,314  RWCPRTN    116.4767  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:58:51  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232875608    CNC  2,000  2,000  WTCO    69.1813  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Limit   69.15  29Jul15 14:53:50  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232874715    ENS  23,987  23,987  NWQI    62.0525  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:47:32  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232872532    CPB  3,000  3,000  STNJ    48.6158  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:35:16  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232871384    XEC  2,500  2,500  ZKB    105.4786  UBS Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:32:39  XNYS  USD  Stock
CPB  3,000  3,000  STNJ    48.6424  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:16:59  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232863189    CPB  2,000  2,000  STNJ    48.6533  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 13:43:10  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232861168    CPB  4,000  4,000  STNJ    48.6842  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 13:26:01  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232856253    Y  7,853  7,853  SIM    18.2700  Fix Cad Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 12:46:50  XTSE  CAD  Stock  A4
232856254    MEG  48,300  48,300  SIM    14.8200  Fix Cad Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 12:46:50  XTSE  CAD  Stock  A4
232856255    FM  107,200  107,200  SIM    11.3000  Fix Cad Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 12:46:50  XTSE  CAD  Stock  A4
232856256    TD  34,200  34,200  SIM    52.6400  Fix Cad Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 12:46:50  XTSE  CAD  Stock  A4


$ awk '{ if($1 ~ "[0-9]+") print $0 ; else print "000000000    "$0 }' /tmp/s
232876337    ROK  37,314  37,314  RWCPRTN    116.4767  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:58:51  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232875608    CNC  2,000  2,000  WTCO    69.1813  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Limit   69.15  29Jul15 14:53:50  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232874715    ENS  23,987  23,987  NWQI    62.0525  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:47:32  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232872532    CPB  3,000  3,000  STNJ    48.6158  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:35:16  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232871384    XEC  2,500  2,500  ZKB    105.4786  UBS Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:32:39  XNYS  USD  Stock
000000000    CPB  3,000  3,000  STNJ    48.6424  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 14:16:59  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232863189    CPB  2,000  2,000  STNJ    48.6533  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 13:43:10  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232861168    CPB  4,000  4,000  STNJ    48.6842  UBS Sales  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 13:26:01  XNYS  USD  Stock  A4
232856253    Y  7,853  7,853  SIM    18.2700  Fix Cad Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 12:46:50  XTSE  CAD  Stock  A4
232856254    MEG  48,300  48,300  SIM    14.8200  Fix Cad Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 12:46:50  XTSE  CAD  Stock  A4
232856255    FM  107,200  107,200  SIM    11.3000  Fix Cad Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 12:46:50  XTSE  CAD  Stock  A4
232856256    TD  34,200  34,200  SIM    52.6400  Fix Cad Blotter  MONOHAJO  Market   0.00  29Jul15 12:46:50  XTSE  CAD  Stock  A4
```

Comment: A bit more idiomatic: `awk -v prefix="0000000000 " '!/^[0-9]/ {$0=prefix $0}1' file`.

Answer (score 0):

Sed do it completely by itself natively

```
sed '/^[0-9]\{9\}/! s/^/000000000/' YourFile
```

select line not (`!`)  starting by 9 digit (`/^[0-9]\{9\}/`) and add 9 zero in this case (only)